# Access to SQL DB in multithread server app

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

In my server application I want to use DB (SQL Server) but I am quite unsure of the best method. There are clients whose requests comes to threadpool and so their processing is async. Every request usually needs to read or write to DB, so I was thinking about static method which would create connection, execute the query and return the result. I'm only afraid whether opening and closing connection is not too slow and whether some connection limit could not be reached? Is this good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprised that no one mentioned connection pooling. If you think you are going to have a large number of requests, why not just setup a pool with a min pool size set to say 25 (arbitrary number here, do not shoot) and max pool size set to say 200. 
This will decrease the number of connection attempts and make sure that if you are not leaking connection handles (something that you should take explicit care to not let happen), you will always have a connection waiting for you. 
Reference article on connection pooling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx
Another side note, why the need to have the connection string in the code? Set it in the web.config or app.config for the sake of maintainability. I had to "fix" code that did such things and I always swore copiously at the programmer responsible for such things.

Comment: Thank you. Also the static method with connection opening (with specified pooling in the string) would be enough? Then I would call this static method from different threads.

Comment: Yes that would be fairly good. The pooling method is something I use with entlib for very easy data access. I suggest this is also something that you should look into. It makes data access even easier than what you have in the code.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best is to rely on the ADO.NET connection pooling mechanism and don't try to handle database connections manually. Write your data access methods like this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Field1 FROM Table1";
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                // do something with the results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call this method from wherever you like, make it static, call it from threads whatever. Remember that calling `Dispose` on the connection won't actually close it. It will return it to the connection pool so that it can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem like you. Had huge app that i started making multithreaded. Benefit over having one connection open and being reused is that you can ask DB multiple times for data as new connection is spawned on request (no need to wait for other threads to finish getting data), and if for example you loose connection to sql (and it can happen when network goes down for a second or two) you will have to always check if connection is open before submitting query anyway.

This is my code for getting Database rows in MS SQL but other stuff should be done exactly the same way. Keep in mind that the sqlConnectOneTime(string varSqlConnectionDetails) has a flaw of returning null when there's no connection so it needs some modifications for your needs or the query will fail if sql fails to establish connection. You just need to add proper code handling there :-) Hope it will be useful for you :-)

```
    public const string sqlDataConnectionDetails = "Data Source=SQLSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Cata....";

    public static string sqlGetDatabaseRows(string varDefinedConnection) {
        string varRows = "";
        const string preparedCommand = @"
                    SELECT SUM(row_count) AS 'Rows'
                    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
                    WHERE index_id IN (0,1)
                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0;";
        using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(varDefinedConnection))
        using (var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection))
        using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())
            while (sqlQueryResult.Read()) {
                varRows = sqlQueryResult["Rows"].ToString();
            }
        return varRows;
    }


    public static SqlConnection sqlConnectOneTime(string varSqlConnectionDetails) {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(varSqlConnectionDetails);
        try {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show("Błąd połączenia z serwerem SQL." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Błąd: " + Environment.NewLine + e, "Błąd połączenia");
        }
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
            return sqlConnection;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Summary:

Defined one global variable with ConnectionDetails of your SQL Server

One global method to make connection (you need to handle the null in there)

Usage of `using` to dispose connection, sql query and everything when the method of reading/writing/updating is done.

Comment: This won't actually work... If you attempt to use the connection a sedcond time you'll find it's unusable as it's been disposed at the end of the top using{} block

Comment: It will work as i use it. I call sqlGetDatabaseRows every couple of seconds and it works as designed. I don't want to use the connection second time. I start the method, it connects to sql and when it's done with sql query it closes connection and disposes everything. The next time you will want to query database you will have to connect again. I open up new connection in each method that requires connection to sql.

Comment: @Rob can you explain why you think my example is bad. It opens up connection inside Using as suggested in the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx article. It's returned to the pool and can be reused if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that you haven't told us, that would be useful for giving you an answer that's appropriate for you is **what level of load** you're expecting your server application to be under.

For pretty much any answer to the above question though, the answer would be that you shouldn't worry about it. ADO.net/Sql Server provides connection pooling which removes some of the overhead of creating connections from each "var c = new SqlConnection(connectionString)" call.

Comment: Also I can have static method with query argument and call it from different threads since the connection will be pooled?